# Base64_to_stream Turbo power Lockbox 3.6.2 Delphi Xe7 | E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray<System.Byte>' and 'string'

Tags: delphi, encryption, base64, rijndael, lockbox-3

i am trying to make program to encrypt on delphi XE7 and Decrypt on PHP side

i use Lock box 3.6.2 using AES 256 Encryption CBC mode  .

the Delphi XE7 Code :

**Main.pas**

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  TPLB3.CryptographicLibrary, TPLB3.BaseNonVisualComponent, TPLB3.Codec,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit, System.Actions,
  FMX.ActnList, FMX.Menus, FMX.ExtCtrls, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    codecAES: TCodec;
    cryptoMain: TCryptographicLibrary;
    btnEncrypt: TButton;
    actlstMain: TActionList;
    edtSeed: TEdit;
    edtPassword: TEdit;

    rgCipher: TPopupBox;
    rgChainMode: TPopupBox;
    rgTestVectors: TPopupBox;
    btnRandomize: TButton;
    memoOutput: TMemo;
    memoPlaintext: TMemo;
    Action1: TAction;
    Action2: TAction;
    procedure actEncryptUpdate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actEncryptExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure rgTestVectorsClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure rgChainModeClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actRandomizeUpdate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actRandomizeExecute(Sender: TObject);

  private
    procedure LogFmt(const sLine: string; const Args: array of const);
    function SpaceOut(const sCompacted: string): string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses uTPLb_Random, uTPLb_StreamUtils, uTPLb_Constants;

{$R *.fmx}



function StreamToHex(Data: TStream): string;
var
  b: byte;
  sByte: string;
begin
  Data.Position := 0;
  result := '';
  while Data.Read(b, 1) = 1 do
  begin
    sByte := Format('%x', [b]);
    if Odd(Length(sByte)) then
      sByte := '0' + sByte;
    result := result + sByte
  end
end;

procedure TForm2.actEncryptExecute(Sender: TObject);
const
  TestCaseNames: array [0 .. 2] of string = ('Test Vector 1', 'Test Vector 2',
    'Custom');
var
  usPlaintext: String;
  aCiphertext: string;
  OriginalSeed: int64;
  stmCipher: TStream;
  FEncoding : TEncoding;
  sHex: string;

begin
  memoOutput.Lines.Clear;
  case rgCipher.ItemIndex of
    0:
      codecAES.BlockCipherId := Format(AES_ProgId, [128]);
  end;
  case rgChainMode.ItemIndex of
    0:
      codecAES.ChainModeId := CFB_ProgId;
    1:
      codecAES.ChainModeId := CBC_ProgId;
    2:
      codecAES.ChainModeId := ECB_ProgId;
  end;

  codecAES.UTF8Password := edtPassword.Text;
  usPlaintext := memoPlaintext.Lines.Text;
  OriginalSeed := StrToInt64(edtSeed.Text);
  TRandomStream.Instance.Seed := OriginalSeed;
  codecAES.EncryptString(usPlaintext, aCiphertext, FEncoding.UTF8);
  // NextSeed := TRandomStream.Instance.Seed;
  LogFmt('Test case = %s', [TestCaseNames[rgTestVectors.ItemIndex]]);
  LogFmt('Cipher = %s', [codecAES.Cipher]);
  LogFmt('Chain mode = %s', [codecAES.ChainMode]);
  LogFmt('PRNG seed = %d', [OriginalSeed]);
  LogFmt('Passord (UTF-8) = ''%s''', [codecAES.UTF8Password]);

  LogFmt('------------', []);
  stmCipher := TMemoryStream.Create;
  codecAES.Key.SaveToStream(stmCipher);
  sHex := StreamToHex(stmCipher);
  stmCipher.Free;
  LogFmt('key as hex = %s', [sHex]);
  LogFmt('Plaintext (UTF-8)', []);
  LogFmt('''%s''', [usPlaintext]);
  LogFmt('------------', []);
  LogFmt('ciphertext (base64) [Includes prepended IV and block quantisation] =',
    []);
  LogFmt(' ''%s''', [SpaceOut(aCiphertext)]);
  LogFmt('------------', []);
  stmCipher := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Base64_to_stream(aCiphertext, stmCipher);
  sHex := StreamToHex(stmCipher);
  stmCipher.Free;
  LogFmt('ciphertext (hex) [Includes prepended IV and block quantisation] =', []
    );
  LogFmt(' ''%s''', [SpaceOut(sHex)]);
  LogFmt('------------', []);
end;

procedure TForm2.actEncryptUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TForm2.actRandomizeExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TRandomStream.Instance.Randomize;
  edtSeed.Text := IntToStr(TRandomStream.Instance.Seed)
end;

procedure TForm2.actRandomizeUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TAction).Enabled := rgTestVectors.ItemIndex = 2
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  memoOutput.Lines.Clear;
  LogFmt('Select test case and chain mode.', []);
  LogFmt('Enter password and plaintext message and then press the ''Encrypt'' button.',
    []);
end;

procedure TForm2.LogFmt(const sLine: string; const Args: array of const);
begin
  memoOutput.Lines.Add(Format(sLine, Args))
end;

procedure TForm2.rgChainModeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TForm2.rgTestVectorsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  isCustom: boolean;
begin
  case rgTestVectors.ItemIndex of
    0:
      begin
        edtPassword.Text := 'Your lips are smoother than vasoline.';
        memoPlaintext.Lines.Text := 'Leeeeeeeeeroy Jenkins!';
        // Above is constrained to:
        // More than 16 and not a whole multiple of 16 bytes as UTF-8.
        edtSeed.Text := '1';
        rgChainMode.ItemIndex := 0;
        rgCipher.ItemIndex := 0;
      end;
    1:
      begin
        edtPassword.Text := 'ORATIO IN L. CATILINAM PRIMA';
        memoPlaintext.Lines.Text := 'Quo usque tandem abutere, Catili';
        // Above is constrained to:
        // A whole multiple of 16 bytes as UTF-8, excluding the empty case.
        edtSeed.Text := '333';
        rgChainMode.ItemIndex := 0;
        rgCipher.ItemIndex := 0
      end;
    2:
      ;
  end;
  isCustom := rgTestVectors.ItemIndex = 2;
  edtPassword.ReadOnly := not isCustom;
  memoPlaintext.ReadOnly := not isCustom;
  edtSeed.ReadOnly := not isCustom;
  rgChainMode.Enabled := isCustom;
  rgCipher.Enabled := isCustom
end;

function TForm2.SpaceOut(const sCompacted: string): string;
const
  NewLineSpacing = 70;
  BunchSpacing = 6;
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  SetLength(result, 2 * Length(sCompacted));
  i := 1;
  for j := 1 to Length(sCompacted) do
  begin
    if ((j mod NewLineSpacing) = 1) and (j <> 1) then
    begin
      result[i] := #13;
      Inc(i);
      result[i] := #10;
      Inc(i)
    end
    else if ((j mod BunchSpacing) = 1) and (j <> 1) then
    begin
      result[i] := ' ';
      Inc(i)
    end;
    result[i] := sCompacted[j];
    Inc(i)
  end;
  SetLength(result, i - 1)
end;

end.
```

and it can't compile give the fallowing error :

```
[dcc32 Error] Main.pas(125): E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray<System.Byte>' and 'string'
```

**and the PHP side :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW,NOARCHIVE" />
    <META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Tutorial and demostration page for Delphi (TurboPower LockBox3) to PHP symetric cryptography." />
    <META NAME="AUTHOR" CONTENT="Sean B. Durkin">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="cryptography,delphi,php,turbopower,lockbox,lockbox3">
    <title>Delphi-to-PHP Cryptography Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width:  721px)" href="tut.css" /><!-- <== Desktop. -->     
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width:  720px)" href="tut-phone.css" / --><!-- <== Phone and tablet. -->  
 <head>

<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_COMPILE_ERROR);
$password = $_GET["password"];
$ciphertext_trans = $_GET["ciphertext-trans"];
$rawInputCiphertext = $_GET["ciphertext"];
$chain = $_GET["chain"];
$cipherIn = $_GET["cipherIn"];

function radioChecked($param,$value,$isDefault)
{
  $echo = (($param == $value) or ($isDefault and ($param == ''))) ? ' checked="checked" ' : '';
  echo $echo;
  return $echo != '';  
}
?>

<nav>
  <div class="nav-bg"></div>
  <div class="nav-content">
    <h1><a href="http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-index.php?page=Delphi-to-PHP+Tutorial+project+home" title="Go to The Delphi-to-PHP project home"><span class="hidden">Project home</span></a></h1>
    <dl>
      <dt>Date created</dt>
      <dd><time datetime="2012-11-29">29-Nov-2012</time></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
      <dt>Date last modified</dt>
      <dd><time datetime="2012-12-02">2-Dec-2012</time></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>    
</nav>

<h1>Decrypt with PHP from Delphi (TurboPower LockBox3)</h1>
<form id="plainForm" class="floatbox" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Crypto data</legend>
    <label class="first" for="password">Password (UTF-8)
      <input id="password" name="password" type="text" placeholder="Enter TCodec password" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password) ?>" />
    </label>            
    <fieldset class="radio">
      <legend>Transport encoding</legend>
        <label for="ciphertext-trans-base64">
          <input id="ciphertext-trans-base64" name="ciphertext-trans" type="radio" value="base64" 
          <?php radioChecked($ciphertext_trans,'base64',True); ?> />base64
        </label>
        <label for="ciphertext-trans-hex">
          <input id="ciphertext-trans-hex" name="ciphertext-trans" type="radio" value="hex" 
          <?php radioChecked($ciphertext_trans,'hex',False); ?> />hex
        </label>
    </fieldset>             
    <label for="ciphertext">Ciphertext (transport encoded)
      <input id="ciphertext" name="ciphertext" type="text" placeholder="Paste ciphertext here" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rawInputCiphertext) ?>" />
    </label>            
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Options</legend>
    <fieldset class="radio">
      <legend>Chaining mode</legend>
        <label for="chain-cfb">
          <input id="chain-cfb" name="chain" type="radio" 
            value="CFB" <?php radioChecked($chain,'CFB',True); ?> />CFB
        </label>
        <label for="chain-cbc">
          <input id="chain-cbc" name="chain" type="radio"
            value="CBC" <?php radioChecked($chain,'CBC',False); ?> />CBC
        </label>
        <label for="chain-ecb">
          <input id="chain-ecb" name="chain" type="radio"
            value="ECB" <?php radioChecked($chain,'ECB',False); ?> />ECB
        </label>
    </fieldset>             

    <fieldset class="radio">
      <legend>Cipher</legend>
        <label for="aes-128">
          <input id="aes-128" name="cipherIn" type="radio" 
            value="AES-128" <?php radioChecked($cipherIn,'AES-128',True); ?> />AES-128
        </label>
        <!-- Extend here with more ciphers as required. Note: PHP does not support AES-256. -->
    </fieldset>             

    </fieldset>             
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Decrypt" />
</form>
<?php if ($chain) { ?>
<?php
function purgeWhiteSpace($sparseHex)
{
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $sparseHex);
}
function expandWithWhiteSpace($compactHex)
{
// TODO: Insert white space for visual benefit. Bunch the brown spaces
//  into words of 6 characters, and then separate words with a single space.
//  Between every 10th word and 11th word, use a new-line ($0D) instead of space.
//  Assume that $compactHex ONLY consists of characters 0..9 and A..F .
    return $compactHex;
}
function displayableMultiline($str)
{
// TODO: Assume $str ONLY consists of characters whose code-points are below
//  137. Insert '<br />' before each $0D character.
    return $str;
}
function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $hex2 = purgeWhiteSpace( $hex);
    $str='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex2)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $str .= chr(hexdec($hex2[$i].$hex2[$i+1]));
    }
    return $str;
}   
function strToHex($str)
{
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
    {       
        $addend = dechex(ord($str[$i]));
        if (strlen($addend) < 2)
          $addend = '0' . $addend;
        $hex .= $addend;
    }
    return $hex;
}

$normalisedRawCiphertext = purgeWhiteSpace( $rawInputCiphertext);
if ($ciphertext_trans == 'base64')
{ 
  $ciphertext = base64_decode( $normalisedRawCiphertext);
}
else
{
  $ciphertext = hexToStr( $normalisedRawCiphertext);
}

if ($cipherIn == 'AES-128')
{
  $cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
  $cipherName = 'AES-128';
}
else
{
  // Extend here with more ciphers as required. Note: PHP does not support AES-256.
  $cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128; // Example only.
  $cipherName = '???';           // Example only.
}

if ($chain == 'CFB')
    $mode = 'ncfb';  // Proper block-mode CFB. There is no constant for this.
  else if ($chain == 'CBC') 
    $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
  else  
    $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

$blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size( $cipher, $mode);
$keySize = mcrypt_get_key_size( $cipher, $mode);

// Work-around PHP bugs.
if (($cipher == MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128) and ($keySize == 32))
  { $keySize = 16; }   // AES-128 key size is 16 bytes.
if (($cipher == MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256) and ($blockSize == 32))
  { $blockSize = 16; } // AES-256 block size is 16 bytes.

$ivSize = $blockSize; // Always. mcrypt_get_iv_size() is pointless.

if ($chain == 'ECB')
{
    $iv = str_pad( 'NOT USED', 16, chr(0));
    // $ciphertext unchanged.
}
else
{
    $iv = substr( $ciphertext, 0, 8);
    $iv = str_pad( $iv, $ivSize, chr(0));
    $ciphertext = substr( $ciphertext, 8);
}

$ciphertextLen = strlen( $ciphertext);
if  (($ciphertextLen > 0) && ($ciphertextLen < $blockSize) && ($chain == 'CBC'))
 { $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CFB; } // CFB 8-bit. This is NOT the same as CFB.

if (strlen($password)==$keySize)
  {
    $key = $password;
  }
else
  {
    $shaPassword = sha1( $password, True);
    for ($key = ''; strlen( $key) < $keySize; $key .= $shaPassword) {}
    $key = substr( $key, 0, $keySize);
  }  

$countBlocks = $ciphertextLen / $blockSize;
$countWholeBlocks = floor( $countBlocks); 
$isRound = $countBlocks == $countWholeBlocks; 
if ($isRound)
    {
    $lastBlockSize = 0;
    }
  else
    {
    $countBlocks = $countWholeBlocks + 1;
    $lastBlockSize = $ciphertextLen - ($countWholeBlocks * $blockSize);
    }     
$isCipherStealing = ($mode == MCRYPT_MODE_CBC) && ($countWholeBlocks >= 1) && !$isRound;
if ($isCipherStealing)
    { // Reverse ciphertext stealing.
/* 
Ciphertext stealing algorithm - Encryption:
  Mix     := Enc( CV[N-2], X[N-2]);
  Steal   := Last( B-b, Mix);
  Recycle := X[N-1] + Steal;
  Y[N-2]  := Enc( CV[N-2], Recycle);
  Y[N-1]  := Head( b, Mix);

Ciphertext stealing algorithm - Decryption:
  Recycle := Dec( CV[N-2], Y[N-2]);
  Steal   := Last( B-b, Recycle);
  Mix     := Y[N-1] + Steal;
  X[N-2]  := Dec( CV[N-2], Mix);
  X[N-1]  := Head( b, Recycle);  
*/  
    // 1. Recycle := Dec( CV[N-2], Y[N-2]);
    $Recycle = mcrypt_decrypt ( $cipher, $key, substr( $ciphertext, 0, $countWholeBlocks * $blockSize), $mode, $iv);
    $reconUpToX_N_3 = substr( $Recycle, 0, ($countWholeBlocks - 1) * $blockSize); // X[0]..X{N-3]
    $Recycle = substr( $Recycle, ($countWholeBlocks - 1) * $blockSize, $blockSize);

    // 2. Steal := Last( B-b, Recycle);
    $Steal = substr( $Recycle, $lastBlockSize, $blockSize - $lastBlockSize);

    // 3. Mix := Y[N-1] + Steal;
    $Y_N1 = substr( $ciphertext, $countWholeBlocks * $blockSize, $lastBlockSize);
    $Mix = $Y_N1 . $Steal;

    // 4. X[N-2]  := Dec( CV[N-2], Mix);
    $reconUpToX_N_2 = mcrypt_decrypt ( $cipher, $key, substr( $ciphertext, 0, ($countWholeBlocks - 1) * $blockSize) . $Mix, $mode, $iv);

    // 5. X[N-1] := Head( b, Recycle);
    $reconX_N_1 = substr( $Recycle, 0, $lastBlockSize);

    // Putting it alltogether.
    $recon = $reconUpToX_N_2 . $reconX_N_1;
    }
  else
    { // Normal decyrption.
    $recon = mcrypt_decrypt ( $cipher, $key, $ciphertext, $mode, $iv);
    }
if (($chain == 'ECB') and ($recon != ''))
  { // Trim ECB padding.
  $last = strlen($recon);
  for ($l = strlen($recon); ($l >= 0) and (ord($recon[$l])==0); $l--)
    {$last = $l;}
  $recon = substr( $recon, 0, $last-1);
  }
?>
<hr />
<h2>Output</h2>
<h3>Summary2</h3>
<p>Cipher is <em><?php echo $cipherName; ?></em></p>
<p>Block size is <?php echo $blockSize; ?> bytes</p>
<?php if ($isRound) { ?>
  <p>Given ciphertext was a round <?php echo $countBlocks; ?> blocks long.</p>
<?php } else { ?>
  <p>Given ciphertext was a <?php echo $countWholeBlocks; ?> whole blocks long and <?php echo $lastBlockSize; ?> bytes in an odd block.</p>
<?php } ?>
<p>Key size is <?php echo $keySize; ?> bytes</p>
<p>Given chain mode was <em><?php echo $chain; ?></em></p>
<p>Given password was <em>&apos;<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password); ?>&apos;</em></p>
<p>Ciphertext as hex is...</p>
<code><?php echo '[' . $ciphertextLen . '] ' . displayableMultiline( expandWithWhiteSpace( strToHex( $ciphertext))); ?></code>
<p></p>
<p>Reconstructed plaintext message is <em>&apos;<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $recon); ?>&apos;</em></p>
<p></p>
<h2>Debug</h2>
<p>Key as hex is...</p>
<code><?php echo '[' . strlen($key) . '] ' . expandWithWhiteSpace( strToHex( $key)); ?></code>
<p>IV as hex is...</p>
<code><?php echo '[' . strlen($iv) . '] ' . expandWithWhiteSpace( strToHex( $iv)); ?></code>
<p>$countBlocks = <code><?php echo $countBlocks; ?></code></p>
<p>$countWholeBlocks = <code><?php echo $countWholeBlocks; ?></code></p>
<p>$isRound = <code><?php echo $isRound ? 'True' : 'False'; ?></code></p>
<p>$isCipherStealing = <code><?php echo $isCipherStealing ? 'True' : 'False'; ?></code></p>
<p>$lastBlockSize = <code><?php echo $lastBlockSize; ?></code></p>
<p>$Recycle = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($Recycle) . '] ' . strToHex( $Recycle); ?></code></p>
<p>$recon X[0..N-3] = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($reconUpToX_N_3) . '] ' . strToHex( $reconUpToX_N_3); ?></code></p>
<p>$Steal = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($Steal) . '] ' . strToHex( $Steal); ?></code></p>
<p>$Mix = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($Mix) . '] ' . strToHex( $Mix); ?></code></p>
<p>$recon X[0..N-2] = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($reconUpToX_N_2) . '] ' . strToHex( $reconUpToX_N_2); ?></code></p>
<p>$recon X[N-1] = <code><?php echo '[' . strlen($reconX_N_1) . '] ' . strToHex( $reconX_N_1); ?></code></p>
<p>Reconstructed plaintext as hex is...</p>
<code><?php echo '[' . strlen($recon) . '] ' . expandWithWhiteSpace( strToHex( $recon)); ?></code>
<?php } ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

i don't have any problem on it till now but i have one question in case of 256 AES i shall use **MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128** or **MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256**

thanks you in advance for helping !

Comment: That error doesn't tally with the code. Line 125 is `Base64_to_stream(aCiphertext, stmCipher);`. And nowhere there is `TArray<Byte>`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And that is the problem. ;-) The routine expects a byte array and it gets a string... I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line fails:

```
Base64_to_stream(aCiphertext, stmCipher);
```

Now, `Base64_to_stream` is declared in `TPLB3.StreamUtils` like this:

```
procedure Base64_to_stream(const Base64: string; Destin: TStream);
```

If you were attempting to call that `Base64_to_stream` then you would not see a compilation error. Since you don't include `TPLB3.StreamUtils` in your uses clause, one can only assume that one of your units defines an different `Base64_to_stream` that accepts `TArray<Byte>` as its first argument.

**Update**

Judging by your unit names, and the link supplied by @TOndrej, it very much looks like you are mixing and matching LockBox implementations. These units, `uTPLb_Random`, `uTPLb_StreamUtils` and `uTPLb_Constants` would all appear to be from a different LockBox implementation.

I suggest that you take a look at where you are getting these different LockBox implementations from. You should be using exactly one LockBox implementation. And perhaps you should consider not using search paths and instead explicitly adding the units to your project. That way you won't accidentally be able to use units that you don't want to use.

Comment: ...or he is using a different version of LockBox (3.6.2).

Comment: @TOndrej I don't think LockBox has ever had a function `Base64_to_stream` that accepts a byte array as its first argument

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tplockbox/code/ci/default/tree/run/utilities/uTPLb_StreamUtils.pas)'s one that does, for example (even though the unit name is different). There could be more versions floating around.

Comment: the problem was i use :uTPLb_StreamUtils.pas it have  `Base64_to_stream ` and it's need byte arrays ,
`function Stream_to_Base64(ASource: TStream; const ATransform: TBytes = nil): TBytes;
`

Comment: @TOndrej I've updated. Thanks. I assumed that the uTPLb units were the asker's code. But they do indeed seem to be from a different LockBox implementation. The user seems to have more LockBox implementations that is prudent!